# How to implement FRESH update in Freya

Tags: release-freya, software-installation, updates

I wish to customize the Elementary OS and deploy it to end user for use, following are two required requirements.

1. all end-users' elementary OS version must match the version of original OS which is located in the server. if the version is different from the server, an unattended update will be started in back-end.
2. all end-users' setting must match with the setting of original OS which is located in server(except files in tmp), which means there is no personal data in this OS, once any changes are found, a re-image process will be triggered, or the OS in end-user's PC will be re-installed in unattended way. all these process will be triggered automatically.

If I wish to implement above features, what I need to do, any thoughts/ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netboot the server in ReadOnly and save tmp files to the local disk. Create a **cron job** that checks if the files in /home/user have changed. If so, format the disk, restart and let it netboot again.

Already did something like this in our school with RPIs...

Comment: Thank a lot, Phil, with respect, but there is no netboot install for elementary OS,  [link](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/776/is-there-a-netboot-install-for-elementary)?

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-pxe-server-ubuntu/